# delete contacts from windows phone 7.1 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contacts

Can I delete contact from windows phone 7.1 using windows phone 7.1 sdk and c# ?

example : I have "mero" contact and I want to delete it to make new one with some new information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to internal restrictions, you cannot alter or delete user information on the phone (in this case - contact information) through the Windows Phone SDK. Certainly, you can do this if you try working outside the sandbox, but that will have its own barriers.

**TL,DR:** No.